# Debugging inline assembly with Xcode

Tags: iphone, assembly

I have written some gcc ARM inline assembly in iphone sdk 3.1.2
however the breakpoints don't get hit (infact anywhere in the c file that contains it). How can i debug it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In xcode 4.2:

Set a breakpoint on the inline _asm statement
Set Product->Debug Workflow->Show Assembly When Debugging = yes
Run
When stops at breakpoint open the 'Debugger Output' window (bottom right) - (default is 'Target output')
type si at the gdb prompt then press enter (for single step)
etcetera